# In what way is Jorge Amado's Home Is the Sailor a modernist novel?

Tags: history-of-literature, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, home-is-the-sailor

The Wikipedia article about Jorge Amado's [*Home Is the Sailor* / *Os velhos marinheiros ou o capitão de longo curso*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Is_the_Sailor_(novel)) describes this work as a "Brazilian modernist novel". The corresponding [Portugese](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Os_Velhos_Marinheiros_ou_o_Capit%C3%A3o_de_Longo_Curso) and [Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_vecchi_marinai) Wikipedia articles contain no similar claims. The novel was written in 1961, long after what I know as the heyday of [literary modernism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_modernism), which I associate with the period from around 1900 (or a bit later) until about 1940.

Many resources about modernism in literature focus exclusively on European and North-American authors. See for example the list of authors in [Modernism Lab](https://campuspress.yale.edu/modernismlab/) (hosted at Yale). A similar focus can be seen in the following passage from ["Modernism and the Modern Novel"](http://www2.iath.virginia.edu/elab/hfl0255.html) at *The Electronic Library* (emphasis mine):

> The term modernism refers to the radical shift in aesthetic and cultural sensibilities evident in the art and literature of the post-World War One period. The ordered, stable and inherently meaningful world view of the nineteenth century could not, wrote T.S. Eliot, accord with "the immense panorama of futility and anarchy which is contemporary history." Modernism thus marks a **distinctive break with Victorian bourgeois morality**; rejecting nineteenth-century optimism, they presented a profoundly pessimistic picture of a culture in disarray. This despair often results in an apparent apathy and moral relativism.

Brazil was never part of the British Empire and by the time *Home Is the Sailor* was published (1961), the Victorian era was probably a distant memory even in what was left of the British Empire, let alone in South America. For these reasons, the definition of modernism in Brazilian literature would probably be based on somewhat different characteristics than in Europe.

What characteristics of *Home Is the Sailor* make this work a modernist novel? Or is the claim incorrect?

---

Note: I listed a few differences between realism and modernism in the question [In what way is Jorge Amado's novel *Jubiabá* a modernist novel?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20040/2191). I did not wish to repeat them here.

Comment: The Wikipedia article you cite mentions modernist works from the 1960s and later (and periodizations that apply to European literature may not match exactly with South America). This question reads like "do my homework" - what characteristics do you associate with literary modernism, and what if any do you find in the novel?

Comment: @StuartF The fact that "periodizations that apply to European literature may not match exactly with South America" is a reason why I'm looking for an assessment based on the novel's features, rather than an argument against asking the question. I listed a few differences between realist and modernist novels in a [related question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/20040/2191) and did not want to repeat them here. "Do my homework"? Is that why you downvoted the question? I graduated from university more than two decades ago.